# Google chronicle api - What value needs to be pass in artifact_domain query param?

Tags: reactjs, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I am triggering google chronicle API to get assets list ( https://cloud.google.com/chronicle/docs/reference/search-api#listassets ) from reactjs application. In this api I am unclear about what value needs to send in artiface_domain query param ?

I already tried passing domain name of my web app, I am getting response status 200 and body of response containing 2 URI in array. But they mention in doc(in above link) sample response it should contain array of asset list as well.
So, I need to figure out exact artiface_domain value which includes assets list.